# Emacs Rename Variable

Tags: emacs, ide

How do I rename a variable in emacs?  Eclipse has a neat "rename" refactoring action which lets you rename a variable in a scoping-aware way, which can be much easier to use than doing localized replace-strings, especially if the variable name is a character like e.  Does emacs have a similar functionality built in?

Comment: Which programming language you mean? Java?

Comment: right now I'm looking at php, but ideally any language.

Comment: As much as I like emacs, I find the lack of this feature really annoying. Maybe there are some new answers out there?

Comment: Note that scope-aware rename depends on the scoping rules for the language being edited, and so while Emacs may have this feature in some specific language editing modes, there's no hope for a generic feature like this that automatically works in all languages (but we can hope for it to become a standard feature that is implemented in the Emacs major mode for all "popular" languages where this feature makes sense).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[iedit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Iedit) was made for this kind of thing.

Comment: iedit while a great replace tool does dumb  replace only, so it's not suitable for intelligent replacement (e.g if the variable name is only a letter as the asker put it)

Comment: Actually iedit along with expand-region allow me to replace symbols within an interesting lexical scope very fast.  This is my go-to tool for renaming variables in all languages.  The length of the symbol isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 30):

New Emacs has `M-s .` to select symbol under cursor, then you can `C-M-%` and it will use currently selected symbol to perform replacements. NOTE This is just plain string replacement, not like the IDE 'rename variable' feature.

Comment: This is a great answer for Emacs. But I strongly disagree with nobody needing a scope-aware rename-variable feature, as provided by Java IDEs.

Comment: Context-sensitive renaming is my most-used feature in IDEs. I definitely need it.

Comment: This worked well for me, renaming a variable `n` in a C program to something more meaningful. It did stop and prompt at `\n` in format strings, but still it is much better than a straight query-replace, which stops at all the `n`s in `printf`, etc.

Comment: Never just list the key binding. Include the function name.

Comment: `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` (bound to `M-s .` ).  From the "Symbol isearch" prompt press `C-h ?` to get further help.   I had to remove a prior customization that I had bound to M-s in the past first.

Answer (score 16):

With the advent of [LSP](https://langserver.org) support in Emacs the actual "rename" refactorings are finally becoming viable in addition to narrowing/iedit/multicursor etc options in other answers, dependent on what the underlying language servers support.

- [emacs-lsp](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) package provides `lsp-rename`
- [eglot](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot) package provides `eglot-rename`

Answer (score 12):

You can use [narrowing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) to only show part of a buffer, and search/replace will only operate in the narrowed region.  For example, you could use <kbd>C-x n d</kbd> to narrow to the current function, or select the region you want and do <kbd>C-x n n</kbd>.  Do your search/replace, then widen back with <kbd>C-x n w</kbd>.  For a single letter variable like `e`, do a `query-replace-regexp` with <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> and use a regexp like `\be\b` so it will only work on individual `e`'s instead of ones inside other words.

**Edit:** Just thought of another thing.  If you select a region, search/replace only works in that area.  So you could just select the scope you want to replace in, then do the `query-replace-regexp` thing.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, this is more or less doable with the Rope refactoring library, for which I advise to use [emacs-traad](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Python#emacs-traad.2C_easy_installation_and_use), in MELPA (straightforward to install and easy to use).

After installation we have the function `M-x traad-rename` which renames a variable in the project.

- [Rope documentation](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/rope.rst)

For simpler search&replace, we have the aforementioned Iedit and also Projectile's `projectile-replace`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your source code language is. Because you mentioned about Eclipse, I assume that it is Java. One option is to use `tags-query-replace` functionality. Use [Excuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with `-e` switch to generate etgas style tags and invoke `tags-query-replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a Eclipse feature, Iedit wont cut it. Its not that smart, what if you got two variables with the same name on different scopes? It would change both of them. This does not happen on eclipse!
You will need language specific tool if you expect that kind of awareness.

With typescript you can use [tide](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide).
With golang you can use [go-doctor](https://github.com/godoctor/godoctor).
Specifically with Java, I could not find anything, but I use [meghanada](https://github.com/mopemope/meghanada-emacs#todo), which is great. But refactoring is on its TODO list! You use also use emacs as a client for eclipse with eclim.

Answer (score 1):

As well as considering the already-suggested [iedit](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit), you can also consider [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) package. Check out an [article](http://bytopia.org/2014/11/26/rename-clojure-symbol-in/) about it, with animation of the live edition.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun replace-var (new)
  "Replace the variable on the cursor"
  (interactive (list
            (read-string (format "Rename %s to: " (thing-at-point 'symbol)))))
  (let ((old (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (mark-defun)
    (replace-string old new)))

(defun replace-old-var (old new)
  "Input the old and new name"
  (interactive "sFrom: \nsTo: ")
  (mark-defun)
  (replace-string old new))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r o") 'replace-old-var)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r v") 'replace-var)
```