# Refactoring with emacs while editing javascript

Tags: javascript, emacs, refactoring

Hi so I am writing a lot of server side javascript and I would like the ability to refactor while editing with emacs. Is this possible? Thanks!

By refactor I mean like how in eclipse while editing Java you can refactor one variable called for example "variableOne" into "variable1" and now all other 15 times you wrote "variableOne" becomes "variable1".

Comment: If by "refactor" you mean *"change the structure of your code"*, then of course you can do that. That's what editors are for, create and modify text (and code is just text). Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Are you talking about automatic refactoring, like some IDEs allow - e.g., to select a function call and click "inline", that sort of thing?

Comment: I mean like how in eclipse while editing Java you can refactor one variable called for example "variableOne" into "variable1" and now all other 15 times you wrote "variableOne" becomes "variable1".

Comment: Also see [Emacs Rename Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920884/emacs-rename-variable) for some more general options. They don't have the advantage of the editor understanding the language, but they do the job in most situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most sophisticated JavaScript refactoring library for Emacs is Magnar Sveen's [`js2-refactor`](https://github.com/magnars/js2-refactor.el). Its [list of supported refactorings](https://github.com/magnars/js2-refactor.el#refactorings) includes

> `rv` is `rename-var`: Renames the variable on point and all occurrences in its lexical scope.

which sounds a lot like what you're looking for. It also supports a number of other very useful common rafactoring actions.

Assuming you're on Emacs 24, I recommend installing it using the [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) repository. If you're still on Emacs 23 you'll have to upgrade or manually install [`package.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) before you can MELPA.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for just `renaming` variables, you might also want take a look at [tern](http://ternjs.net/). The advantage it has compared to `js2-refactor` (which I use too) is that it has a concept of projects so you can rename a certain variable across multiple files in a project. It also provides other features like `jump-to-definition` and `auto-completions` (which are quite accurate).

Here are some general options for renaming a variable

1) [Multiple cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) - It has a useful command `mc/mark-all-like-this-dwim`, which marks all the occurences of the selected text in current `context` you can then edit all the occurrences simultaneously.

2) [Wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) - This package enables one to apply changes done in `grep` buffer to respective files. This is useful when I have to replace a word across many files, in such situations use `rgrep` to search the word in multiple files. Then enable `wgrep` in the resulting `grep` buffer, mark the word to replaced with `multiple-cursors` (you can also use query-replace), make the changes and then do `wgrep-save-all-buffers` and all my changes are saved!

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be more about renaming variables than about refactoring in general. The two places to start for information about using Emacs to rename parts of your code are these:

- Emacs Wiki [***Search and Replace***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySearchAndReplace) category page.  This includes search-and-replace ***across multiple files*** (e.g. of your project).
- The Emacs manual: use **`C-h r`** to enter the manual from Emacs.

  Then use hit the key `i` to look something up in the index (with completion):

  **`i search and replace commands`** takes you to the section about replacement commands.

  **`i search and replace in multiple files`** takes you to the section about *Searching and Replacing with Tags Tables*.

For Emacs support for projects, see the Emacs Wiki [***Projects***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryProject) category page.